# Memcached Session manager - high miss: Wasted is 100%

Tags: java, tomcat, memcached

Tried searching but could not find. We are using java / tomcat with [Memcached Session Manager](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration). There is only one memcached server. Even with one person tesitng, we are getting approx 50% miss. Any suggestion.

Update as request----
Tomcat's config.xml

```
<Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
    memcachedNodes="n1:10.10.1.151:11211"
    sticky="false"
    sessionBackupAsync="false"
    lockingMode="auto"
    requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
    />
```

Adding cache stat

### Cache Size Stats

```
Used   6.0   MBytes
Total  512.0 MBytes
Wasted 6.0   MBytes
```

Comment: are you caching data that should not be cached?  Is cache size too small for your data set?

Comment: all data we are caching is serializable. We are using tomcat's default session sharing in clustering. Though we have only one tomcat & one memcache server.
tomcat config.xml
<Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
    memcachedNodes="n1:10.10.1.151:11211"
    sticky="false"
    sessionBackupAsync="false"
    lockingMode="auto"
    requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
    />
 
If required can provide more information.

Comment: That is a pre-req.  Many cases, cache hit is caused by low cache size.  You need to go back and see what data you are putting into cache. (And update the question with more information)

Comment: Cache Size Stats
------------------
Used   6.0   MBytes
Total  512.0 MBytes
Wasted 6.0   MBytes

Comment: Request more things that you've previously requested? increase the cache size? It's a cache. The things you're asking for ... aren't in it.

Comment: as per cache size is concerned, we have plenty, please check update comment. The data is in there. I have checked with get command on phpMemcachedAdmin. Getting the data.